# Caching dynamodb getTable() call

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have some use cases due to which I can't use DynamoDBMapper. Instead I am using DynamoDB V2 Document API.

Whenever my API gets a request, I need to get hold of "Table" class instance. Hence I invoke `dynamoDB.getTable("TABLE_NAME")`;

However is this call costly? Will it make more sense if I maintain Map of all table instances in memory on startup and refer the Instance from map instead of calling from `DynmaoDB.getTable()` API?

I also have similar query regarding `table.getIndex()` API call.

Comment: Please, specify your programming language. Is it `Java`?

Comment: Java API of dynamo dB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation - DynamoDB#getTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.html#getTable(java.lang.String)):

> Returns the specified DynamoDB table. No network call is involved.

This method will only construct a `Table` instance, think it as a factory method. Since the code is not open source, I cannot say for sure, but I'm guessing they also have an inner cache layer similar to what you suggest.

So I won't bother at all mantaining a dictionary (which, by the way, ***you would have to make thread-safe***) for such call.

Comment: Thread safe would not be a concern, as I am planning to build an immutable map during startup

Comment: I just a ran a load test myself by having a loop of 10000 times. On an average the direct table.getTable() took 25 Micro seconds where as a simple look from map has some 300 Nano seconds. As 25 micro seconds is considerably low latency for my use-case, i am not going with caching and instead calling the dynamoDB table API directly.